# Qt: Should I route my signals from an external object through my mainWindow or directly to the ui elements

Tags: qt, qt4

Im building an application where a few objets outside the mainWindow will need to talk to be connected to the ui elements, just simple on click events triggering member functions. I was wondering whether to Add slots to the main window that connect to each ui element so that I only ever need to interface my external objects with one ui object, the main window, or whether I should directly connect my objects signals to the individual ui elements slots.

Also could someone share an example of how to connect a signal from an external object into the mainWindow, I'm very new to this and until now I've always added all my code to the mainWindow to keep things simple but i know thats bad practice so i think its time to move on.

Thanks all

j

Comment: I think this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239664/qt-best-practice-append-signals-and-slots-to-my-main-window-or-create-new-class) might be related to what you seek for.

Comment: @Fezvez Same user asked those two questions. :)

Comment: i wasn't going to mention that:) thanks for the heads up anyhow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in syntax between connecting an "external" object or an "internal" one to a slot. The `connect` call takes two object pointer (from/to) and doesn't really care about where they are (except if you're using threads).

The Qt [Signals and slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/signalsandslots.html) documentation has all you need to know about these connections, and the examples show real code that uses signals. (The [analog clock](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/widgets-analogclock.html) for instance uses a QTimer which is "external" to its main window.)

There is no one-size-fits-all answer to the "where should I put my public slots" question. Do what is easier to maintain/more logical for your particular scenario. Having all your "external" signals routed to a single object that dispatches them is "clean" from an interface (API) point of view, but it means you'll need to maintain more code than if you routed the signals directly to the object that needs to react on them.

Comment: thats great thanks, im still a little confused about to to connect signals from an external object. i.e. if im inside the MainWindow implimentation i can connect a signal with this, SIGNAL(...); but if im not inside the MainWindow object then i cant access with 'this' obviously, i just dont know what to put in there, i guess its not a question of syntax but of scope, j

Comment: the first argument to `connect` is a `QObject*`. You can use any pointer to QObject there, not just `this`. Same thing for the third argument (as long as the have the right signal/slot obviously)

Comment: Sorry for being slow, but i cant get my head around this still. I'm trying `connect(&extProcess,SIGNAL(outLog),&commandLogBox,SLOT(appendPlainText));` but i get `extProcess` (my own QObject) and `commandLogBox` (a QTextEdit object inside MainWindow) and `connect` 'not declared in this scope' errors. I know that the signals and slots exist because i am transferring working code from MainWindow to a new object, im just getting confused with pointers as is the learner tradition. (this code is in the main loop by the way, not in any object).  thanks

Comment: post a new question if you have a specific problem. But please read a good C++ reference too. "not declared in this scope" means you're trying to access variables from somewhere where they are not visible. This is nothing Qt specific, and is basic C/C++ scoping.

Comment: point taken, humans are just much better at explaining things that books:) the last thing i want to to is get on anybody's wick though. thanks for the help, j